# KQL - How to enrich an event by matching an IP address to an IP range from a Sentinel Watchlist?

Tags: kql, azure-log-analytics, azure-sentinel

I am trying to enrich events from an Analytic Rule with a Watchlist as I did in Splunk.
My event contains a field named SourceIP that obviously contains an IP address.

I have a Watchlist that contains all subnets of different locations:

| Office | Range |
| --- | --- |
| New York | 10.10.1.0/16 |
| Paris | 10.20.1.0/24 |

I need to match the IP address from the event with the IP range from the Watchlist to output the field Office and its value.

I made this in splunk with a lookup, but I don't know how to do this in KQL.

```
|lookup office-ranges.csv Range AS SourceIP OUTPUT Office
```

I tried to do this in KQL with join operator but it doesn't allow me to match the IP

```
|join kind=fullouter (_GetWatchlist(office-ranges) on Ranges
```

And also tried with lookup:

```
| lookup kind = leftouter _GetWatchlist(office-ranges) on $left.SourceIP  $right.SearchKey
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll probably want to use the inbuilt [ipv4_lookup](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/kusto/query/ipv4-lookup-plugin) like this:

```
let Watchlist = datatable(Office:string, Range:string) [
'New York', '10.10.1.0/16',
'Paris', '10.20.1.0/24'
];
let Events = datatable(Description:string, SoureIP:string) [
'Event 1', '192.168.0.50',
'Event 2', '10.10.6.50',
'Event 3', '10.20.1.50',
'Event 4', '10.20.2.50'
];
Events
| evaluate ipv4_lookup(Watchlist, SoureIP, Range, return_unmatched = true)
```

| Description | SoureIP | Office | Range |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Event 1 | 192.168.0.50 |  |  |
| Event 2 | 10.10.6.50 | New York | 10.10.1.0/16 |
| Event 3 | 10.20.1.50 | Paris | 10.20.1.0/24 |
| Event 4 | 10.20.2.50 |  |  |

Comment: It works! Thank you!
Just to share more details, I made a function named "OfficesRange" with the watchlist that just contains:

`_GetWatchlist("Office-Range")
| project Office, Range`

Then I just needed to add this command to obtain the Offices in the results:

`| evaluate ipv4_lookup(OfficesRange, SourceIP, Range, return_unmatched = true)`

And it works perfect!